# How to terminate a query that is displayed in Session Monitor in Toad for MySQL

Tags: mysql, toad

I had 2 queries in the editor window.  I cancelled it 2X as I had the wrong info in my query.  I stopped the background process and thought I was terminating the query.  I went into the Session Monitor and see those 2 queries in the Query status under the Activity column.  My question is, are these 2 queries still running as they are NOT in sleep mode?  If they are how can I terminate them?

Thanks for any help/direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up a MySQL console, do a

```
 show full processlist;
```

to find the ID of your queries.  and then kill that particular ID with something like this

```
 kill 32843;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Justin.  I appreciate your time and reply.